# JPA when persisting entity gives an error im using glassfish server and claasses are genrated from netbeans IDE

Tags: jpa

```
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
... 35 more
```

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: com.rentsys.entity.Watch[ id=50 ] is not a known entity type.**
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at com.rentsys.sessionbean.RemoteEJBSessionBean.businessMethod(RemoteEJBSessionBean.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor492.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:205)
    ... 67 more

================================================================

```
public class RemoteEJBSessionBean implements RemoteEJBSessionBeanRemote {


@Override
public void businessMethod() {

EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("RentSysPU");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    String a="Called";
    Watch phon = new Watch(10);
    phon.setId(50);
    phon.setMachine("aaaaaaa");
    em.persist(phon);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
    emf.close();

}

// Add business logic below. (Right-click in editor and choose
// "Insert Code > Add Business Method")
```

}

=======================================

@Entity

@Table(name = "WATCH", catalog = "", schema = "CHARAKA")

public class Watch implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id

@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "ID")
private Integer id;
@Size(max = 100)
@Column(name = "MACHINE")
private String machine;

public Watch() {
}

public Watch(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getMachine() {
    return machine;
}

public void setMachine(String machine) {
    this.machine = machine;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Watch)) {
        return false;
    }
    Watch other = (Watch) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.rentsys.entity.Watch[ id=" + id + " ]";
}
```

}

========================================
persistance.xml

```html
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="RentSysPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>rentsys</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.rentsys.entity.Phone</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Nobody will help you without seeing code and full stacktrace.

Comment: so you don't list the class "Watch" in persistence.xml and say "exclude-unlisted-classes" and then are surprised when the JPA provider doesn't know about this "entity" ? really?!

Comment: <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> u sugesstion this will work ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue
Issue was with galssfish server you need to mentioned all the db realted proerties inthe connection pool and assign that connection pool to the Datasource via Admin panel of the glass fish

DB URL
Username
Password
DB Name
i cant upload image of my config since i dnt have rep for it plz concatct anuboady anybody neeed